# Numerous Select Dropdowns PHP Populated - Slow Page Load

Tags: php, performance, drop-down-menu

I have a number of `<select>` dropdowns each populated via loops through simple numbers (no database involved at this point).

See image:

[image]

These each contain times from 08:00 to 24:00 (0:00).

I used my usual method of creating a loop to echo the options, however, because of the number of them, the page experiences quite bad slow down.

I was wondering if there was a better approach to this at all?

Here is my PHP function to echo the options:

```
function printHours($interval = 30, $selected = "07:00", $start = "0") {
    $selected = date("G:i", strtotime($selected));
    for($i=$start; $i < 24; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < 59; $j+=$interval) {
            $time = str_replace(":0", ":00", "$i:$j");
            echo '<option value="' . $time . '"';
            if($selected == $time) {
                echo ' selected="selected"';
            }
            echo '>' . $time . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '<option value="0:00">0:00</option>';
}
```

Comment: How many options are there? I can't imagine this code would slow it down very much. What value is stored in `interval`?

Comment: These look like custom javascript drop down boxes to me. It's more likely the javascript that would be causing performance issues rather than the php.

Comment: It's an accordion style interface so there will be numerous more dropdowns in the other sections, each dropdown would have roughly 40 options, generates a lot of html.

Comment: @Novocaine88 That's a good point actually, they are zurb-foundation framework's boxes, I hadn't thought of that, will try disabling and check if it's any better.  I think it translates each one into `<div>`s and list items so it's quite likely.

Comment: You were right, about three times faster without the additional javascript, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you save those strings in a variable instead of echoing, you would only need to loop once for all those dropdowns.

Comment: Using an `ob_start` or similar I take it?

Comment: no, just append the output to a variable with .= instead of echoing.

I would use arrays though as you need to be able to match each on its own for the selected check

Comment: Yeah was just going to add about the selected issue, if I used an array I'd be back to the same problem anyway surely?  If anything, looping through the standard numbers (original method) would be better performance-wise than looping through an array.

Comment: @Charlie Since the performance issues are very unlikely to be caused by those loops, it actually doesn't matter. I was just answering the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
printHours(30, '12:00', '08:00');

function printHours($interval = 30, $selected = '', $start = '00:00', $end = '24:00') {
    $period = new \DatePeriod(
        new \DateTime($start),
        \DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes'),
        new \DateTime($end));

    foreach($period as $interval) {
        $time = $interval->format( "H:i" );
        echo '<option value="', $time, '"', $time === $selected ? ' selected' : '', '>', $time, '</option>';
    }
}
```